# How to convert InputStream into Source?

Tags: java, android, validation, xsd

I want to validate *xml* document using *xsd* schema file stored on my device.
Here is my example code:

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

// schema file on my device
InputStream isSchema = context.getResources().openRawResource(xsd_file);
// InputStream => Source conversion
Source schemaSource = ????
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaSource);

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
```

**Question:** How can I convert InputStream into Source required by SchemaFactory::newSchema method ?

Comment: hmmm maybe http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You don't convert, you wrap it.

```
Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(isSchema);
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource%28java.io.InputStream%29